# Cassandra CQLSH OperationTimedOut error=Client request timeout. See Session.execute[_async](timeout)

Tags: cassandra, timeout, cqlsh, operation

I want to transfer data from one Cassandra cluster (reached via 192.168.0.200) to another Cassandra cluster (reached via 127.0.0.1). The data is 523 rows but each row is about 1 MB. I am using the COPY FROM and COPY TO command. I get the following error when I issue the COPY TO command:

```
Error for (8948428671687021382, 9075041744804640605):
OperationTimedOut - errors={
'192.168.0.200': 'Client request timeout. See Session.execute[_async](timeout)'},
last_host=192.168.0.200 (will try again later attempt 1 of 5).
```

I tried to change the `~/.cassandra/cqlshrc` file to:

```
[connection]
client_timeout = 5000
```

But this hasn't helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear which version of Cassandra you're using here so I'm going to assume 3.0.x

The `COPY` function is good but not always the best choice (i.e. if you have a lot of data), however for this though you might want to check some of your [timeout settings](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml.html#configCassandra_yaml__range_request_timeout_in_ms) in cassandra

The docs here show a [pagetimeout](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshCopy.html#cqlshCopy__description) setting too which may help you.

Moving data between two clusters can be done a number of other ways. You could use of any of the following:

1. The [sstableloader](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsBulkloader.html)
2. One of the drivers like the [java driver](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver-dse/1.2/)
3. Using spark to copy data from one cluster to another, [like in this example](https://github.com/phact/dse-cluster-migration)
4. Using OpsCenter to [clone a cluster](https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-opsc/opsc/online_help/services/opscBackupCloneCluster.html)
5. The [cassandra bulk loader](https://github.com/brianmhess/cassandra-loader) (I've known a number of people to use this)

Of course #3 and #4 need DSE cassandra but its just to give you an idea. I wasn't sure if you were using Apache Cassandra or Datastax Enterprise Cassandra.

Anyway, hope this helps!

Answer (score 24):

You may want to increment the request timeout (default: 10 seconds), not the connect timeout.

Try:

```
cqlsh --request-timeout=6000
```

or add:

```
[connection]
request_timeout = 6000
```

to your `~/.cassandra/cqlshrc` file.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the copy timeout the correct way is to use the PAGETIMEOUT parameter as already pointed.

> copy keyspace.table to '/dev/null' WITH PAGETIMEOUT=10000;

Trying to set the --request-timeout=6000 with cqlsh does not help in that situation.

Answer (score 1):

Hi besides the following,

**1.Check  tombstones**
In cassandra tombstones degrade the performance of reads and following issue occur OperationTimedOut: errors={'127.0.0.1': 'Client request timeout. See Session.execute_async'}, last_host=127.0.0.1
**Note**
When we insert data in to the table with null values in columns it creates a tombstones. we need to avoid null inserts inside the table.
There are multiple options available like **unset**(https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-csharp-driver-api/html/T_Cassandra_Unset.htm) and **ignoreNulls** (https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/5_saving.md) property in spark.
You can check your table status using the following command
nodetool tablestats keyspace1.tablename

**2.Remove Tombstones**
If your working on a single node you can remove tombstones by altering your table 
ALTER  table keyspace1.tablename
WITH **gc_grace_seconds** = '0';

**3.read_request_timeout_in_ms**:Configure the value  in cassandra.yaml file to increase timeout for a read request

Comment: Thank you!! Tombstones was a problem for us indeed! We sorted that out by setting gc_grace_period to something low for certain tables in which rows were getting deleted often/cells being set to null.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone needs to increase default timeout in [python Cassandra client](https://github.com/datastax/python-driver):

```py
cas_cluster = Cluster(..)
cas_session = cas_cluster.connect(cas_keyspace)

cas_session.default_timeout = 60 # default is 10 sec.

cas_query_resultset = cas_session.execute("..")
```